# Visibility of interface symbols in iOS Categories

Tags: ios

I am using iOS Categories to compartmentalise my code. For the class "aClass" to access symbols from the category file "aClass+categoryName", I must declare those symbols in "aClass+categoryName.h". I want these symbols only to be visible to "aClass". However unless the compiler behaves differently, symbols that are meant to be private to an "aClass" object, are in fact public to all objects. Is my understanding correct? If so is there a way to share symbols from a category whilst keeping them private to the class ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your understanding is correct - anything defined in a header file is public.

The only way to create truly 'private' declarations, would be within you `aClass.m` implementation file, to declare them within a private category, e.g.

```
@interface aClass() // --> private anonymous category
@property (nonatomic, strong) id somePrivateProperty;
@end

@implementation aClass

- (void)someFunction() {
    // can access self.somePrivateProperty
}
@end
```